# checking usertype in if/else not working codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have my controller function as:

```
public function verify()
    {
    $token= $this->uri->segment(3);
    $email_verification=$this->load->site_model->verifyEmailAddress($token);

        if ($email_verification=== FALSE)
        {
            redirect('site/index');
        }
        else
        {



$type=$this->load->site_model->select1($token);
            //print_r($type);
            if($type['user_type']=="Employer"){
                redirect('site/emp');
                }
                else{
                    redirect('site/seek');
                }

        }
    }
```

and my model is:

```
<?php
class Site_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->database();

    }
    public function insert($token)
    { 
        $data = array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'phone'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
        'user_type'=>$this->input->post('utype'),
        'token'=>$token,
        );

        $this->db->insert('tbl_user',$data);

        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $html ="http://localhost/jobs/hmvc/index.php/site/verify/".$token;
        $config = array(
       'protocol'  => 'smtp',
       'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
       'smtp_port' => '465',
       'smtp_user' => 'someone@gmail.com',
       'smtp_pass' => 'something',
       'mailtype'  => 'html',
       'starttls'  => true,
       'newline'   => "\r\n"
       );
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->From("someone@gmail.com");
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('test');
        $this->email->message('<b>Hi '.$name.' </b><p>Welcome! You’re almost done.!Click the link to confirm your email address..</p>'.$html);
        //$this->email->send();

        if($this->email->send()) {
            echo '<script>alert("Email sent successfully")</script>';
            } else {
        $this->email->print_debugger();
        }

    }


    public function verifyEmailAddress($token)  
        {  
        $data=array('email_verification'=>1);
               $this->db->where('token',$token); 
               $this->db->update('tbl_user',$data);
                  return true;

        }
public function select1($token) {         
                  $this->db->select('user_type');
                  $this->db->from('tbl_user');
                  $this->db->where('token',$token);
                  return $this->db->get()->row();
    }


?>
```

while em running the code an error showing as Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobs\hmvc\application\modules\site\controllers\site.php on line 89

How could I resolve this problem? What does this error in codeigniter mean?

Comment: `insert()` is not returning anything.

Comment: `$type['user_type']???` your $type value does not contains nothing and always goes to else condition.

Comment: so how could I proceed? @ Shaiful Islam

Comment: add `return $data;` at the last line for insert function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php  
 public function insert($token)
    { 
        $data = array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'phone'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
        'user_type'=>$this->input->post('utype'),
        'token'=>$token,
        );

        $this->db->insert('tbl_user',$data);
        $ret =$this->db->insert_id();


        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $html ="http://localhost/jobs/hmvc/index.php/site/verify/".$token;
        $config = array(
       'protocol'  => 'smtp',
       'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
       'smtp_port' => '465',
       'smtp_user' => 'someone@gmail.com',
       'smtp_pass' => 'something',
       'mailtype'  => 'html',
       'starttls'  => true,
       'newline'   => "\r\n"
       );
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->From("someone@gmail.com");
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('test');
        $this->email->message('<b>Hi '.$name.' </b><p>Welcome! You’re almost done.!Click the link to confirm your email address..</p>'.$html);
        //$this->email->send();

        if($this->email->send()) {
            echo '<script>alert("Email sent successfully")</script>';
            } else {
        $this->email->print_debugger();
        }

        if($ret){
         // $this->db->where('id', $ret);
         // $query=$this->db->get('tbl_user');
        //  $result = $query->result_array();
         // return $result;
          return $this->select1($token);
        }

    }
public function select1($token) {   
    $this->db->select('user_type'); $this->db->from('tbl_user'); 
    $this->db->where('token',$token); 
    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

You can try this function for insert. Please make this function in same model.

Comment: Please checked my new answer

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
    public function verify()
    {
        $token= $this->uri->segment(3);
        $email_verification = $this->load->site_model->verifyEmailAddress($token);

        if ($email_verification != 1)
        {
            redirect('site/index');
        }
        else
        {
            $type=$this->load->site_model->select1($token);
            //print_r($type);
            if($type['user_type']=="Employer"){
                redirect('site/emp');
            }
            else{
                redirect('site/seek');
            }

        }
    }
```

In Model

```
    public function verifyEmailAddress($token)
    {
        $data=array('email_verification'=>1);
        $this->db->where('token',$token);
        $this->db->update('tbl_user',$data);
        return 1;

    }
    public function select1($token) 
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT user_type FROM tbl_user WHERE token = '$token' ");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that I may be late by 1 year, but all the answers are just code, **while stackoverflow answers should be more of a guidance to the problem solving.**

The reason you get this error is because your **Select1** function in the model returns an object: `return $this->db->get()->row();`

And in your controller you save the returned value as

```
$type=$this->load->site_model->select1($token);
```

Then later on, you have if-else statement, where the condition is:

```
$type['user_type']=="Employer";
```

You are trying to get variable `$type` with a key(index) of `"user_type"` which is an array, while your model returns the object.

So the solution is to change from `$type['user_type']=="Employer"` to `$type->user_type == "Employer"` in the controller, which actually refers to the object's property named "user_type".